# Jenkins pipeline shared library can't invoke method in src directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I want to invoke method of src directory from vars directory, which it works in IDE. But it seems not work in Jenkins.

1.project structure

```
├── src
│   └── foo
│       └── DemoClass.groovy
└── vars
    └── varDemo.groovy
```

2.Content of DemoClass.groovy

```
#!groovy
package foo

class DemoClass {
    def testDemoMethod() {
        println("src DemoClass testDemoMethod")
    }
}
```

3.Content of varDemo.groovy

```
#!groovy

import foo.DemoClass

def testVarsDemo() {
    println("vars varDemo.groovy testVarsDemo")
}

def testVarsInvokeDemoMethod() {
    println("vars varDemo.groovy testVarsInvokeDemoMethod")
    def demoClass = new DemoClass()
    demoClass.testDemoMethod()
    println("end vars varDemo.groovy testVarsInvokeDemoMethod")
}
```

4.Jenkins pipeline

```
@Library('tools') _
varDemo.testVarsDemo()
varDemo.testVarsInvokeDemoMethod()
```

5.execute result in pipeline

```
 > git checkout -f b6176268be99abe300d514e1703ff8a08e3ef8da
Commit message: "test"
 > git rev-list --no-walk c1a50961228ca071d43134854548841a056e16c9 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] echo
vars varDemo.groovy testVarsDemo
[Pipeline] echo
vars varDemo.groovy testVarsInvokeDemoMethod
[Pipeline] echo
end vars varDemo.groovy testVarsInvokeDemoMethod
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

It seem like `demoClass.testDemoMethod()` not work. Why can't invoke `demoClass.testDemoMethod()`? If I want to invoke the method in `src` directory, what should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without reimplementing your code sections locally, Here are some differences I notice between yours and mine that is working.

**JENKINSFILE**

1. I don't have a space before the underscore on my @Library line
2. Immediately after my @Library line I am importing my shared library class that implements the methods I want to call.  In your case this would be `import foo.DemoClass`
3. My call to my method is of the form `(new DemoClass(config, this)).testVarsInvokeDemoMethod()`

**SHARED LIBRARY CLASSES**

4. I don't have `#!groovy` in any of my groovy classes.
5. My class is public and implements Serializable

Hopefully one of these difference is the source of why its not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

We need to follow the below structure

```
 src/packagename/GroovyFile.groovy 
 vars/callFromJenkinsPipelne.groovy
```

The jenkins pipeline should be like this .

```
 library('libracyname@Branchname')
    callFromJenkinsPipelne()
```

Inside the vars file ( callFromJenkinsPipelne) , we can call the  groovy file which is in src folder

> ```
>    //code in vars folder groovy file will be like this 
>  for callFromJenkinsPipelne groovy file 
>      def call(){
>     GroovyFile groovyFile = new com.jenkins.mypackagename.GroovyFile()
>     groovyFile.methodName(parameters) 
>     }
> ```